# Hibernate, return custom object with Criteria or HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

there is a way to return a custom object with a criteria query or hql query?

For example, i have a class MyClass with a constructor MyClass(int id, String text), i want incapsulate my queries result in this class:

```
"select new MyClass(e.id, e.name) from Example e"
```

MyClass is not an entity, but a simple custom class.

Thank all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HQL queries it works exactly as you showed (class name should be fully qualified, i.e. with package).

Although, as far as I understand, it's not supported in Hibernate Criteria API, but supported in JPA 2.0 Criteria API as `CriteriaBuilder.construct()`.

Comment: thank you, you are rigth, the problem is i can't mix class instance with others parameters: select new MyClass(e.text), e.id from Example e. There is a workaround for this?